# Select from 2 MySQL Tables in 1 HTMl Table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have one problem to list records from two MySQL tables in one HTML Table.
In MySQL I have: Table 'Fields' with 'ForUser','ForCategory', 'FieldName', and Table 'Content' with 'ForUser','ForCategory', 'ForField', 'FieldContent'. Now i want to list FieldName as HTML Table Head, and  FieldContent as HTML Table Body.
I has listed Table Head with:

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli($SERVERNAME, $USERNAME, $PASSWORD, $DBNAME);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Greska: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "SELECT FieldName FROM Fields WHERE ForUser = '$User_Check' AND ForCategory = '$CategoryName'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      echo "<table class='table table-bordered'><thead><tr>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<th>".$row["FieldName"]."</th>";
}
    echo "</tr></thead>";
}      
else {
    echo "<div style='margin-top: 18px;' class='alert alert-danger'><b>$lang[MANAGE_CATEGORY_ALERT]</b></div>";
}
echo "</table>";      
$conn->close();
?>
```

Now I don't know how to list FieldContent for each FieldName in Table Head,
respectively I Dont know how to get Field Name in

```
$sql = "SELECT FieldContent FROM Contnt WHERE ForUser = '$User_Check' AND ForCategory = '$CategoryName' AND ForField = '$ForField'";
```

as array and after that do:

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

for each $SQL than display all data in HTML Table Body in regard to their 'ForField'.

Tanks

Answer (score 3):

Please Used MYSQL With Join Query you can get your solution 
[See Link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-joins.htm)

Comment: I'm think I can't use Join Query because I have several WHERE parameters and WHERE parameter from Content Table $SQL depends on first $SQL, respectively econd $SQL depends on $FieldName from first $SQL, more precisely on ForField.

Comment: Or can anyone give me any example?